# How to specify display name for web app configured without web.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, web, web.xml

How to specify **display name** for web application (war) configured programmatically in java with [WebApplicationInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) only. I have something like this

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
     ...
  }
}
```

With `web.xml` this look like this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
version="3.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"    metadata-complete="false">
   <display-name>my app</display-name>
   ...
</web-app>
```

Is this possible in Java configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ServletContext` interface does not provide a method to change the display name. There are some other things that it also doesn't let you do. In those cases, you have to use the deployment descriptor, ie. the `web.xml`.

Note that it has a [`getServletContextName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServletContextName%28%29) method which

> Returns the name of this web application corresponding to this
>   ServletContext as specified in the deployment descriptor for this web
>   application by the display-name element.